# Why isn't my palindrome checker working?

Tags: c++, palindrome

I can't for the life of me get my code to work. It identifies palindromes correctly, but for some reason, some non-palindromes words get marked as palindromes. Not all, just sum. And biggest headache of all, I can't figure out the correlation between of the non-palindromes that pass.

Any other feedback is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <limits> 

using namespace std;

int main() {

const int a(15);
char Line[a + 1];
int i;


do {
    cout << "Enter a possible palindrome" << endl;
    cin.getline(Line, a + 1);
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Line); i++) {
        Line[i] = (char)tolower(Line[i]);
    }

    int c = strlen(Line);
    for (int i = 0; i < c / 2; i++) {


        while (!(((int)Line[c - 1 - i] >= 'a' && (int)Line[c - 1 - i] <= 'z') || ((int)Line[c - 1 - i] >= 'A' && (int)Line[c - 1 - i] <= 'Z'))) {
            c--;
        }

        if ((Line[i] == Line[c - 1 - i]))
        {
            cout << "is a Palindrome" << endl;

        }
        else
            cout << Line << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
        break;

    }




} while (strcmp(Line, "END") != 0);

return 0;
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a word that is incorrectly identified as a palindrome? And have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger?

Comment: `while (!(((int)Line[c - 1 - i] >= 'a' && (int)Line[c - 1 - i] <= 'z') || ((int)Line[c - 1 - i] >= 'A' && (int)Line[c - 1 - i] <= 'Z'))) ` -- There is an `isalpha()` function in C++ that replaces all of that.  In addition, it works for ASCII and non-ASCII systems.

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger you will immediately see the problem. Please do learn how to debug, it will save you from a lot of trouble and is a lot faster than waiting for someone to tell you. Hint: it will say "antikythera" is a palindrome but not "bananas"

Comment: I think I figured out the correlation- they all start and end with the same letter. I'm a little embarrassed I hadn't caught that.

Comment: It seems that your program doesn't check for numbers as well. That should be easy to incorporate.

Comment: As a newbie, have fun with this: char *rev = strrev (strdup (Line)); if  (strcmpi (Line, rev) == 0) cout<<" is a pallindrome"; free (rev);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is a palindrome if the condition `Line[i] == Line[c-1-i]` holds for all `i < c/2`. You print out that its a palindrome provided two of the characters match.

Eg: Your program would say:

```
"abdca" //is a palindrome since the first and last character match.
```

Comment: A loop should fix that, I think. Thanks for helping out the newbie!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is intricacy a bit. Let's assume that the input is always readable, so you just need to `cin >> Line;`. Let n is length of string. Now we use a loop from 0 to n / 2 to check the symmetry of string. If `Line[i] != Line[n - i - 1]` that means `Line` is not symmetry (palindrome) then we just need to print the result and `return 0`. If the program pass the loop that mean `Line` is pallindrome. This problem is quite easy. For me, the way you think of it is complex a bit.